# NSAllowArbitraryLoadsinWebContent disable internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using `NSAllowArbitraryLoads` flag set to `YES`, and i told by one of my ads provider that i need to add `NSAllow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content` set to `YES` too.
But when i done it a lot of requests bring me this error :

```
The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.
```

Any idea how i can handle this problem?

Comment: Can you please share your URL which you are opening in webview?

Comment: @Pushkraj I get this error for every http request i made

Comment: Yes means that all requests are going to secure servers with ssl and https

Comment: @MTA
If you set `NSAllowArbitraryLoads` to `YES`, then you can only access `https server URL's and web services` to app.